# (HTML/Js) Authentication Using Prompts and Promises

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, promise, prompt

I have a bit of code below:

```
async function authenticateUser() {
        let authenticated = false;
        socketTx = io();
        socketRx = io.connect();

        var user = prompt("Please enter username", "");
        var pass = prompt("Please enter your password", "");

        socketTx.emit('authChannel', {username: user, password: pass});

        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              socketRx.on('authChannel', function(auth) {
                //console.log(auth);
                resolve(auth); 
              });
        });

        authenticated = await promise;
        console.log(authenticated)
        if (authenticated == false) {
          user;
          pass;
        } else {authenticated == true}
      }
```

The `socketTx` is sending the `user`/`pass` data to the server for PAM authentication in `Node.js`. `socketRx` receives a `true`/`false` for whether the user was authenticated.

The desired behavior is for the prompts to spam the user until the right "login" information is provided. I thought I captured this behavior in calling the variables `user`/`pass` again once the authentication is verified to be false but the prompts do not display a second (or more) time(s). I can confirm that I receive the correct info at `console.log(authenticated)`.

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `if (authenticated == false)` block call `authenticateUser()` again, recalling the prompts won't perform the requests again, so the whole function will need called

Comment: @Thomas__ Thanks! Works flawlessly! If you post answer ill accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment:

```
async function authenticateUser() {
        let authenticated = false;
        socketTx = io();
        socketRx = io.connect();

        var user = prompt("Please enter username", "");
        var pass = prompt("Please enter your password", "");

        socketTx.emit('authChannel', {username: user, password: pass});

        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              socketRx.on('authChannel', function(auth) {
                //console.log(auth);
                resolve(auth); 
              });
        });

        authenticated = await promise;
        console.log(authenticated)
        if (authenticated == false) {
          authenticateUser(); // recall method
        } else {authenticated == true}
      }
```